# JQuery 's .change not registerning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a novice JQuery programmer and am running into some trouble. I am attempting to create boxes that only come active after the previous box has been given a value. I have successfully done this for the first disabled box, StatSelection, but when I make my selection from this box it fails to trigger the .change function. Could somebody more experienced please enlighten me as to why this might be the case. So I can get it to work for StatSelection, but when I select a value from StatSelection's list it refuses to register an onchange event. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3. Thanks

HTML

```
 <div class = "container">
  <form role="form">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
              <label for="YearSelect">Select a year</label>
              <select id="YearSelection" class="form-control">
                <?php
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                    echo '<option>';
                    echo $row['yearID'];
                    echo "</option>";
                  }
                ?>
              </select>
            </label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>
              <label for="StatSelection">Select a stat</label>
              <select id="StatSelection" class="form-control" disabled>
              </select>
            </label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>
              <label for="Amount"> Pick Table Size</label>
              <div id="TableSize">
              <select id="SizeofTable" class="form-control" disabled>

              </select>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#YearSelection" ).change(function(){
      $("#StatSelection").replaceWith($('<select id="StatSelection" class="form-control">'));
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>Gbatting</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>AB</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>R</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>H</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>2B</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>3B</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>HR</option>');
      $("#StatSelection").append('<option>RBI</option>');
    });
    $("#StatSelection").on('change',function(){
      alert( $("#StatSelection").val());
      $("#SizeofTable").replaceWith($('<select id="SizeofTable" class="form-control">'));
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="5">5</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="10">10</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="15">15</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="20">20</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="25">25</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="30">30</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="40">40</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="50">50</option>');
      $("#SizeofTable").append('<option value="100">100</option>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tired doing a `console.log()` within each `change`?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an entirely new DOM element, which means that you have to register a new javascript handler. Also you should take advantage of jQuery's daisy chaining and multiple parameter passing features:

```
$("#StatSelection").on('change',function(){
    alert( $("#StatSelection").val());
    $("#SizeofTable").replaceWith(
        $('<select id="SizeofTable" class="form-control">').append(
            '<option value="5">5</option>',
            '<option value="10">10</option>',
            '<option value="15">15</option>',
            '<option value="20">20</option>',
            '<option value="30">30</option>',
            '<option value="40">40</option>',
            '<option value="50">50</option>',
            '<option value="100">100</option>'
        ).on("change", function () {
            // Put the next replace code here
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank's I will try that out!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `replaceWith` you replace `#StatSelection` with a new element, so your second `change` does not work, try this:

```
  // $("#StatSelection").replaceWith($('<select id="StatSelection" class="form-control">'));
  $("#StatSelection").removeAttr('disabled')
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/yuten/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is providing `#StatSelection` to the `on` function as a selector. What you have would work if it looked like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#StatSelection', function(){
    ...
});
```

See a complete example here: http://jsfiddle.net/byM2h/

What you need to keep in mind here is that you cant bind to an element before it is created. The above statement works because `document` is already going to be defined when it runs. When you ran this:

```
$("#StatSelection").replaceWith($('<select id="StatSelection" class="form-control">'));
```

What you did is create a whole new element, that by default has nothing bound to it.